# useffect inside <outlet> component does not trigger

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, use-effect

Parent component:

```
  <Main  props... >
   <LinksArray />
   <Outlet context={investorId}/>
  </Main>
```

outlet component

```
const NewBoards: React.FC = () => {
     let { boardId } = useParams();
     // this does not
     useEffect(() => {
         console.log('ue trigger page change',boardId )
     }, []); 

     // this triggers (because of an argument 
     useEffect(() => {
       console.log('ue trigger page change',boardId )
     }, [boardId ]);
    
     return (

     <>
      {console.log('>rerender')}
      <p> newBoards</p>
      <p>{boardId}</p>

    </>
     )

}
```

NewBoards is an outlet element, I would love for useEffect to trigger on a ROUTE (ex. boards/123 to boards/345  ) change, without passing boardId, however useEffect does not trigger on the address change unless I`m passing boardId to the dependency array. boardId param does change.

Also I would like to know why that useEffect does not trigger. I can't find anything related to it on the react router v6 official documentation

edit:

I have also noticed that states are saved. States inside outlet component( NewBoards ) do not refresh to initial ones.

edit ( router definition ) :

```
  {
    path: '/boards/',
    element: authorized ?  <Boards1 />  : <Login />,
    children: [{
      path: '/boards/:boardId',
      element: authorized ? <NewBoards /> : <Login />,
    }]
  },
```

Comment: Can you share the route definitions ?

Comment: Please describe the problem you're facing in a better way. If only the param boardId is changing in your url, then where is the problem in passing boardId in the dependency array?

Comment: @AymenHammami Curiosity. As far as I understand, it should work without passing an argument because whole outlet component should re-render.Since it does not work as I expected it to, clearly I am making some error in judgment.

Comment: @Kaneki21 I have added router cfg. I am using object structure, but I don't see how that can cause an issue.

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic the useEffect with  empty dependency array [] will only be executed once in the component's lifetime, the other one with [boardId] will call the function inside each time boardId changes. If you want a useEffect to be called on each re-render independant of a variable, don't pass a second argument / array at all

Comment: what I can think of is that your component is mounted beforehand and only on route change that useffect is getting triggered, i.e. why on second useffect you are getting console.log. can you use "/boards" in the route config for the parent

Comment: @AymenHammami Component should rerender, it should start new lifecycle when I switch the route. 

If i am going from board/1234 to board/5467 whole outlet component should rerender. 

It should throw away old outlet and create new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see from your comments you've seriously misunderstood what is happening between the `Outlet` and the nested `Route` components that are rendering their content, i.e. `element` prop, into it.

Assuming `authorized` is true then the following route config:

```
{
  path: '/boards/',
  element: authorized ?  <Boards1 />  : <Login />,
  children: [{
    path: '/boards/:boardId',
    element: authorized ? <NewBoards /> : <Login />,
  }]
},
```

will produce the following rendered routes:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path="/boards" element={<Boards1 />}>
    <Route path="/boards/:boardId" element={<NewBoards />} />
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```

Where I think your understanding goes awry is in thinking that when the URL path changes from `"/boards/123"` to `"/boards/345"` that the `Boards1` component rendered on `"/boards"` will rerender and remount the `Outlet`. It won't. This means that the `Outlet` it is rendering also doesn't do anything other than output the result of the currently matched route.

A second point of confusion/misudnerstanding on your part is thinking that when the URL path changes from `"/boards/123"` to `"/boards/345"` that `<Route path="/boards/:boardId" element={<NewBoards />} />` will unmount and remount a new instance of the `NewBoards` component. This is also not the case. The `NewBoards` component will remain mounted and will simply rerender. This is an optimization by `react-router-dom` as it's a lot more work to tear down and remount a component than it is to simply rerender it with some different props/context/etc.

The routed components using the route path params necessarily need to "listen" to changes to the params if they need to issue `side-effects` based on the param values. This is why the `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array runs only once when the `NewBoards` component was mounted (*not each time the route changes*) and the `useEffect` hook with the `boardId` param as a dependency correctly reruns each time the `boardId` value changes.

```
const NewBoards: React.FC = () => {
  const { boardId } = useParams();

  // Run this when component mounts, occurs once per mounting
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ue trigger page change', boardId);
  }, []); 

  // Run this when the `boardId` param updates 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ue trigger page change', boardId);
  }, [boardId]);

  // Run this each render, i.e. no dependency array at all!
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('>rerender');
  });

  return (
    <>
      <p>newBoards</p>
      <p>{boardId}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```